# Dataframe AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'icol'

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to read excel file in python but I am getting error

```
    Attribute error: 'Dataframe' object has no attribute 'icol'
```

Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    file = pd.ExcelFile("reports.xlsx")
    sheet = pd.read_excel("reports.xlsx",sheetname=0)

    item = sheet.icol(0)
    amount = sheet.icol(1)
```

Other details: Python 3.6.1 & Windows 10.

Please check:

1) [Sample Excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbzYs.jpg)

2) [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvePP.png)

Comment: Which pandas version? icol is DEPRECATED http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.icol.html

Comment: O yeah ! icol is deprecated. thanks @e.arbitrio ! Now I have used .iloc[:, i]

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.icol.html, the `icol` method is deprecated, use `iloc` instead.

*Edit:* I see in the comments that you found that already.